# DKIM tool Integration with my custom email sending application

Tags: dkim

I want to develop an email sending application like www.formget.com or similar.
Can anyone will help how to integrate OpenDKIM with my email sending application?
Any idea from anyone would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the first question is how you send your mails? Via your own mailserver postfix, sendmail, ... or you use a smtp relay sendgrid, mailgun, emailsocket,...

The easiest way is using a smtp relay Service, this company create the dns records (SPF, DKIM, DMARC) and you must only set this records on your domain.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your acknowledgment. I want to use own SMTP relay, example - I'll send email through PowerMTA and my frontend application would be connected to this via SMTP connection. Though, my application is not so efficient as like formget or Intersipre but still I want to have inbuilt DKIM generator tool. Please let me know if this details help you answering my question.

Comment: Hi you can set the DKIM sign direct on PowerMTA you dont need OpenDKIM for this issue. https://www.powermta.co.za/dkim-records-in-powermta/

Comment: okay.. I got you. but please see my requirement as below:

1. I have an application from where my customer is sending the email campaigns.
2. Before a customer starts sending the email they need to register their sending domain in our system.
3. My system should be able to generate a DKIM key for the domain provided by client automatically which should be updated by them domain's DNS later - [This is where I am stuck, currently I am generating DKIM key manually and asking  the client to update this]

I hope you got requirement now.

Comment: Okay you requirement is generate a public and private key in the application. With the public key you create the dns record for the customer. The private key you can import in the PMTA. Is this a possible solution?

Comment: For example you can create the key with a other library http://php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-pkey-new.php and import the private key in your pmta config

Comment: thank you. I think this should help me. will try to implement this and let you know also :)